# Cell array (or matrices) of matries in R

Tags: r

I'd like to implement a Matlab N by N cell array of N by 2 matrices in R.
Basically the data is of the form of an N by N array and each element of the array is a N by 2 matrices. I need to extract the N by 2 matrices later.
I thought about 3 d arrays in R but still a bit confused.
Thanks.

Below is a Matlab version. I hope to implement this in R. Here I let N =2.

```
A = {}
A{1,1} = [1,2;3,4];
A{1,2} = [5,6;7,8];
A{2,1} = [9,10;11,12];
A{2,2} = [13,14;15,16]
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list with a dimension attribute:

```
MM <- vector("list", length = 4 * 3)
dim(MM) <- c(4, 3)

MM[[1, 1]] <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer (using a dimensioned list) is the best way, but an alternative is a 4-dimensional array:

```
A <- 1:16
dim(A) <- c(2,2,2,2)  # This creates a 4-dim array
A
A[,,1,1]
A[,,1,2]
A[,,2,1]
A[,,2,2]
```

Comment: I thought about array but didn't think of the 4d one... Thanks!